# Method call not working on buttonActionEvent, but will work elsewhere?

Tags: java

I am just trying to close a process, which I do have working (tested). My only issue is that when I'm trying to close this process on a button click, it won't work. The method will work elsewhere to close the process, but for whatever reason it just doesn't work in the button event..

```
public Process p;

public final void openKeyboard() throws IOException {
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd","/c","C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\microsoft shared\\ink\\tabtip.exe");
p=pb.start();
}

public final void closeKeyboard() {
    p.destroy();
}
```

Here is the button event that should call the closeKeyboard method and end the process:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    MainMenu mm = new MainMenu();
    mm.run();
    closeKeyboard();  
}
```

This method won't close the keyboard, but if I call closeKeyboard from another method, it will work... Am I missing something obvious? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you are adding your `ActionListener` to a different `JButton`?

Comment: The button does work, because the main menu works on the button click (opens a new screen). So in theory it should be running that method 100%.

Answer (score 0):

"be aware that if the process that you invoke creates new sub-processes, those may not be terminated (see https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4770092)."

could this be the issue?